# PHP modify value of object property in an array of objects

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user model, with a profile_details column which holds a json_encoded object of the user profile information. The object is as shown below

```
$user->profile_details: {
   'name' : 'Wayne', 
    'books' : [
        { id: 1, title : 'Rich Dad' ,  isbn: 9780},
       { id: 3, title : 'Business school' ,  isbn: 8891} 
        ] 
}
```

How do I modify the value of the 'id' property of the books array after retrieving the user model from the database.

Below is what I have tried.

```
$user =User::find(1);
$newBooks = array();

if($user) {

    $profile_details_decoded = json_decode($user->profile_details) ;
    foreach($profile_details_decoded->books as $book) {
     $book->id = 28;
      array_push($newBooks, $book);
} 

$user->profile_details->books = $newBooks;

}

dd($user->profile_details->books);
```

I expected the `$newBooks` array to replace the `$user->profile_details->books` array.

Please someone should kindly guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `profile_details` hold json_encoded data, you have to work on the copy of the array and assign the array completely to the column.

```
    $profile_details_decoded = json_decode($user->profile_details);
    $newBooks = [];
    foreach($user->profile_details->books as $book) {
        $book->id = 28; // whatever logic you want fpr changing id
        $newBooks[] = $book;
    } 
    $profile_details_decoded->books = $newBooks
    $user->profile_details = $profile_details_decoded;
```